# I want to look back at questions/answers for reference

Tags: support

There are a few questions and answers on superuser that I've noticed that have been very beneficial to me figuring out problems with my computer. I didn't ask these questions nor provide an answer. I know if you do any of these 2 actions, a link is provided in a populated list in your profile. Is there any way of referencing these questions/answers other than just using the "search" query? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep! Just click the little star beneath the vote arrows, and it'll be added to [your favorites list](https://superuser.com/users/111691/christopher-chipps?tab=favorites).

[image: favorite button]

Answer (score 2):

If you upvote or downvote a question or an answer, a link is stored on your profile beneath the **Votes Cast** section

You can go straight to the list of votes by appending `?tab=votes` to the url of your profile

For example, to see my votes I would go to the following url

> https://meta.superuser.com/users/193782/axrwkr?tab=votes

I've found that you can't view other peoples votes, only your own